# How to find the link behind an image or swf file from a Har File

Tags: python, regex, flash, selenium-webdriver, firebug

Right now I'm getting a HAR file by using a combination of Selenium WebDriver, netexport, and firebug. I can find the image and swf files however I'm having trouble locating the url that they link to.

For example I can get the URL of the a swf file let's say http://my.swf.here.swf
I do not however have a decent heuristic for finding what that file links to. I downloaded the file and tried clicking on it from my desktop which didn't yield the link, nor did decompiling the file and peeking in the code inside. I was hoping to see something that would allow me to do something similar to moat.com. I'm trying to learn python over the summer.

I'm using regex, and I can find (most) swfs using this:

```
'([http|www|HTTPS|HTTPS|https|Https|Http][^\"|\'|;|,|(|)|{|}|=]*\.swf')
```

I tried:

```
'([http|www|HTTPS|HTTPS|https|Https|Http][^\"|\'|;|,|(|)|{|}|=]*\.swf.*href=.*\"' but I can't find any links.
```

An example of the har files my program is pulling can be found on my github:
https://github.com/thirab/FlashY/tree/master/har

Essentially I can find the image but now what that image links to. Any ideas or better heuristics?

Comment: Could you please give us the content (even partial) of the source text you are searching in?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I added a link to the har files that the program finds.